# Thank you very much for your or you're

Tags: grammar

is it

Thank you very much for your

or

Thank you very much for you're

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. When asking about usage, you must provide the full context you will use a word or phrase, or we will be unable to help you. Second, throughout StackExchange, you are expected to demonstrate that you have attempted some research on your own; at the very least, indicate which one you think might be correct or not and why. The short answer is that *you're* is a contraction of *you are*, and whether or not you would choose one or the other depends on whether *you are* is the intended meaning. Please take the site [tour] and review the [help].

Answer (score 2):

It's

> Thank you very much for your …

Remember that `you're` is an abbreviation of `you are`. The apostrophe is a clue. :-)